# List of lists python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, canopy

I have the following Python 2.7 code:

```
#-*- coding: latin1 -*-
kw=int(input("Precio del Kw: "))
numeroCasas=int(input("Cantidad de Casas: "))
consumos={}
consumo={}

for i in range(numeroCasas):
    print("Casa numero " + str(i+1) + ": ")
    consumo["propietario"]=raw_input("\tNombre del Propietario: ")
    consumo["numCasa"]=raw_input("\tNumero de Casa: ")
    consumo["consumo"]=int(raw_input("\tConsumo: "))
    consumos={i : consumo}

print("\nCompletado. \nValor del Kw: "+ str(kw) +"\n\nListado de 

usuarios:\n\nNro\t|\tNombre\t|\tCasa\t|\tConsumo\t|\tTotal a Pagar")

    for i in range(numeroCasas):
        totalPagar = consumos[i]["consumo"]*kw
        print(str(i+1) + "\t|\t" + str(consumos[i]["propietario"]) + "\t|\t" + str(consumos[i]["numCasa"]) + "\t|\t" + str(consumos[i]["consumo"]) + "\t|\t" + str(totalPagar))
```

For `numeroCasas = 1` works, but for `numeroCasas > 1` show a error msg:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\consumo.py in <module>()
     15 
     16 for i in range(numeroCasas):
---> 17     totalPagar = consumos[i]["consumo"]*kw
     18     print(str(i+1) + "\t|\t" + str(consumos[i]["propietario"]) + "\t|\t" + str(consumos[i]["numCasa"]) + "\t|\t" + str(consumos[i]["consumo"]) + "\t|\t" + str(totalPagar))

KeyError: 0
```

What is an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the issue:

```
consumos={i : consumo}
```

You don't need a list of dictionary entries, instead you need a list of dictionaries.

```
for i in range(numeroCasas):
    # read all the stuff in to consumo...
    consumos[i] = consumo
```

Then, to print should be simple as well.

```
for c in consumos:
    print(c)
```

Comment: Thaks, I use `consumos[i] = consumo` instead `consumos={i : consumo}` and works great. I also had to add "consumo = {}" to clean the temporary array "consumo", and print using `for i in usuarios:
    print(consumos[i]['propietario'])`

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the line:

```
consumos={i : consumo}
```

to append elements on a dictionarie, you gotta do it like this:

```
consumos[i] = consumo
```